# MongoDB C# Driver - InsertBatch get affected document count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
 var collection = database.GetCollection<Publication>("Publications");
 var result = collection.InsertBatch(bookCollection);
```

I want to get affected document count. And i am getting AffectedDocumentCount as zero.

What could be wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look at signature:

```
 IEnumerable<SafeModeResult> InsertBatch(
Type nominalType,
IEnumerable<Object> documents,
SafeMode safeMode
```

[SafeMode](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/cac72c74-ae6d-9b2e-a503-303a40104143.htm) can cause postpone you real batch write. Play with `FSyncTrue` (can be very slow) or `True`.

Answer (score 0):

The server only supplies the count of the number of documents affected on an Update operation.

The DocumentsAffected property of a WriteConcernResult comes from the "n" field of the response to the getLastErrorCommand, which will always have a value of 0 for an Insert.